Canonical representation for SDEs / diffusion semimartingales on manifolds
In $\mathbb{R}^d$, there is a "canonical" expression for diffusion semimartingales, given by the SDE $d X_t = b(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dB_t$ or generator $L = b \cdot \nabla + \frac{1}{2} \textrm{tr}[\sigma \sigma^T \nabla^2]$.

Is the same true/possible on a Riemannian manifold? Is there a nice way to express the diffusion semimartingale in terms of a canonical equation depending only on some coefficients?

Thoughts:

There are also SDEs on manifolds (using the Rolling without Slipping constrcution). I.e. let $V_{\alpha}$ be vector fields on $M$ and $W_t \in \mathbb{R}^l$ a driving semimartingale, then $dX_t = V_0(X_t) dt + V_{\alpha}(X_t) \circ dW_t^{\alpha}$. Now here one might hope that it suffices to chose $W_t \in \mathbb{R}^l$ a (Euclidean) Brownian Motion to cover all possible diffusions on manifolds. Unfortunately, in this case we know that the generator $L = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\alpha=1}^l V_{\alpha}^2 + V_0$. Since not all generators of diffusion processes (i.e. second order elliptic PDOs) are representable in terms of vector and tensor fields, this does not suffice. (I am not 100% sure though. Maybe with an embedding, it is always possible. In the same way that the Laplace-Beltrami $\Delta_M$ can only be represented in Hörmander form $\Delta_M = \sum P_{\alpha}^2$ after embedding $M$.)
Of course, we could use the correspondence between the diffusion $X_t \in M$ and its anti-development $W_t \in M$ and refer to the canonical representation of $W$. This does not look to pleasing though as the diffusion behavior of $X$ depends on the whole history of the behavior of $W$.
I heard of SDEs on manifolds driven by a Riemannian Brownian motion. Maybe that could give a nice classification but I could not find a reference to this topic.

